# Python - Write the header without double quotes in pandas(df.to_csv)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, double-quotes

i might be missing a small trick here but i couldn't get it right from today afternoon

I have 4 columns that needs to separated by `~`. Out of this 4 column, one column is having `~` symbol as part of its name itself which is `!~ID`. This is how my output should look

```
!~ID~Rev~Type~Name
```

My code

```
df.to_csv(r'myout.txt', header=['!~ID','Rev','Type','Name'], index=None, sep='~', mode='w')
```

But this always gives me

```
"!~ID"~Rev~Type~Name
```

After seeing couple of post i have tried quoting options

```
df.to_csv(r'myout.txt', header=['!~ID','Rev','Type','Name'], index=None, sep='~', mode='w',
          quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
          escapechar = '~')
```

But this gives me one extra `~` for ID. Please help

```
!~~ID~Rev~Type~Name
```

Comment: The file you're trying to build is not a valid csv. What are you trying to achieve? Why does the separator have to be `~`? Or why wouldn't you tolerate quotes or another escape character?

Comment: @Tranbi Thanks for the comments. i agree that it is not valid. Unfortunately , this file is an input file for my application. It needs to be in this format for our program to read it. We cannot change the program as we are getting that from vendor. Are there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the file you want isn't a valid csv, I suggest you edit the file afterwards to get the desired result:

```
df.to_csv(r'myout.txt', header=['!#ID','Rev','Type','Name'], index=None, sep='~') # replacing the first ~ with # (use any character you like)

with open('myout.txt', 'r+') as f:
    f.seek(1)    # position of #
    f.write('~') # replacing
```